# repeated integration of lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am currently working with Wheeden Zygmund's Measure and Integral. I got stuck on one of the exercises (Ch. 6, Ex. 13).

Let $f \in L(-\infty,\infty)$ (Lebesgue integrable), and let $h > 0$ be fixed. Prove that 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y) \, dy) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx $$

I believe it suffices to prove that $ \frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y) \, dy = f(x) $ using the mean value theorem, but I am not entirely sure. Can anyone give me a hint on this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Fubini's theorem.

Comment: thanks for the hint. could you possibly show how i can apply fubini's thm here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note by Fubini's theorem that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y) dy dx
&= \frac{1}{2h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1_{(x-h, x+h)}(y) \cdot f(y) dy dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \cdot  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1_{(y-h, y+h)}(x) dx dy 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) dy,
\end{align*}
since $1_{(x-h,x+h)}(y) = 1_{(y-h, y+h)}(x)$.

I leave it to you to verify that Fubini's theorem is indeed applicable.